# Definition of atlas in Morita's Geometry of Differential Forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In Morita's *Geometry of Differential Forms* p. 14 after the definition of atlas, he makes the following remark ($M$ is a manifold, $\{(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)\}$ is an atlas of $M$, $V_\alpha$ are the images of $\varphi_\alpha$ in $\mathbb R^n$)

> We remark that even if we cut off from $\mathbb R^n$ the part $V_\alpha$ used to make $M$, $\mathbb R^n$ fills the gap soon and is again complete, so that if the next part $V_\beta$ intersects “the imaginary hole”, $V_\beta$ can be taken out with complete shape. $\mathbb R^n$ is, so to speak, a “fountain” from which the parts of manifolds spring.

I understand the defintion of atlas but I don't understand what he is trying to explain here. What does he mean by "$\mathbb R^n$ fills the gap"?

Comment: Neither do I. I just want to assure you that you can have a successful career in differential geometry without having any clue to what this means.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does anyone know if Shigeyuki Morita is/was any relation to Kiiti Morita?

Comment: I agree with @Deane.

Comment: Perhaps a poor translation from Japanese to English?

Comment: @rschwieb In Japan - 300,000 people have the name Morita.

Comment: @PaulFrost That is neither here nor there.  Only a tiny fraction of that number are mathematicians, and multi-generational mathematicians are not uncommon.  In fact I think I know at least one case of father-son-grandson being PhDs in mathematics.  Anyhow I ask just out of curiosity, fully knowing they are likely unrelated.

Comment: Yes, the $\mathbb R^n$ is a fountain of youth